# compiling synamic arm code

Tags: android, command-line, cross-compiling

I'm building some common gnu/linux console utilities for my Android phone but so far I have only been able to build them statically, with quite a size penalty. Can someone walk me through the steps for synamic compiles using shared libraries?

Here's the script(s) I'm using for configuration:

```
./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi \
CC="arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" \
CROSS_COMPILE="arm-none-linux-gnueabi-" \
CFLAGS=" -static $_XXFLAGS" \
```

for shared:

```
./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi \
CC="arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc" \
CROSS_COMPILE="arm-none-linux-gnueabi-" \
--enable-shared=yes --enable-static=no
```

Do I need to make the libs on my android phone avaiable
to my cross-compiler? Google isn't helping me here.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide the location for the shared libraries that you want to link against.  Please post the error that you're getting for a better answer, but take a look at my answer to

[install 64-bit glib2 on 32-bit system for cross-compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542039/install-64-bit-glib2-on-32-bit-system-for-cross-compiling/5399432#5399432)

You should just need to add the right -L and -Wl,-rpath-link to the CFLAGS variable when you're running *configure*.