# How to compile 64 bit Python library (SIP, for example) at the 32 bit old Mac with py2app?

Tags: python, macos, 32bit-64bit, py2app, python-sip

I need to compile 64 bit libraries for Python (SIP for example) instead 32-bit, compiled by my old 32bit Mac for using to .app bandle at new Macs.

Looks like similar question placed here  [Is it possible to compile a 64 bit executable on a 32 bit system under Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939464/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-64-bit-executable-on-a-32-bit-system-under-ubuntu)

but is looks like a very slow-tuning way, but I need a MANY libs to rebuild - by reason a creation a standalone application with py2app.

All I found that downgrade this kind of process - from 64 to 32 like

```
# python configure.py --arch=i386 -d /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

From here http://www.oak-tree.us/blog/index.php/2009/05/12/pyqt-mac

but

```
# python configure.py --arch=x86_64 -d /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

at 32 bit system - would not helps - after replacing the sip.so in the  app bundle to just-compiled file I get the same error "sip.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture"

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rebuild your entire python distribution, including all the packages as 32 bit architecture. It might be easiest to do this on the old Mac you're developing for.  It's not going to be fast, but it it is not complicated.